# Rails MySQL custom field, raw SQL on runtime

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, custom-attributes

When user opts to create a custom field say Email for a model say Contact(Name,Mobile), is it a crime to execute a system command "mysql -u poi -pjuking db -e 'alter table contacts add column email varchar(255)" and somehow add the :email to attr_accessible in the Contact model....?

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT DO THIS**

Yes, this altering source is a felony (what happens when you a running on multiple machines) you suddenly need to update the cluster.   Same thing goes for the DB.

Instead use Hstore in Postgres or serialize a field with custom attributes if on Mysql.